# Finding unique number of logins from a database based on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with information of when users have logged into my app. There are two columns -

1. User ID
2. Log in date (YYYY/MM/DD)

Each user can have multiple logins in one day.

I want to find the number of unique day logins for each user. For example, if a user logs in five times on 10th October, 2022 and he logs in ten times on 11th October, 2022, and 0 times every other day, then I want the value of '2' next to his id, because he logged in a total of two unique days.

Please note that I need to this using only one file (no intermediate saved files) and I cannot use a CET either.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the **exact** data-type of your `Login date` column? (And why are you only storing the date rather than the full datetime/timestamp? And what timezone are you using?)

Comment: And what is your database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses. @Dai, the exact data-type of Login Date is - DATE. We have other information including timestamp and timezone in other columns, but it is not relevant to this particular use case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio, and later I will export this query as a custom query in tableau.

Comment: @Madhav SSMS isn't an RDBMS, it's a client tool. What **server** version/edition are you running?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, sorry for the confusion, I am a bit new to SQL. Here is some information, hope it helps!

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 13.0.16106.4
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools -13.0.1700.441
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) - 10.0.19041.1

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Rager I was able to write a CTE that gave me the desired results but apparently tableau doesn't accept CTEs in their custom queries.

Comment: @Madhav That's the client version. To get the server version open the "Object Explorer" pane in SSMS and right-click the server at the top and open its Properties pane. It will tell you server info in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the distinct dates per user:

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(DISTINCT LogInDate) 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to reduce the individual login rows to the days a user logged in, then use an aggregate query to count them.  Like so.

```sql
SELECT UserID, COUNT(*) NumberOfDaysLoggedIn
  FROM (SELECT UserID, LogInDate FROM myTable GROUP BY UserID, LogInDate)
 GROUP BY UserID
```

The subquery to generate one row per user per date is

```sql
SELECT UserID, LogInDate FROM myTable GROUP BY UserID, LogInDate
```

but you could also use DISTINCT for the purpose. They do the same thing.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT UserID, LogInDate FROM myTable
```

This happens to be one of the few queries involving dates that will work on all makes and versions of table server.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I had a similar solution before (grouping in a subquery to find distinct rows and using that to do another grouping), but I was getting the same errors then that I am getting now.

Maybe, it is because I am doing something wrong, since I am new this language and the software?

Comment: I have posted the doubts on my g-drive - 

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MBb_qV08aVUTOwZAmbbTdc0mEhTQ0U1J?usp=sharing

Comment: You have a space in `[User ID]`, the name of your column. That probably is incorrect, the column name is probably `[UserID]`. Look at your table definition (open up the columns item to the left in SSMS.

Comment: A friend had told me the same thing, but I know for a fact that the column name is User ID with a space, and I have used it in another queries before without error.                                    However, even after changing the code from brackets to apostrophes, the error in group command still remains.

Comment: Case sensitive?  Please don't expect some rando on the internet, like me, to be able to provide completely correct code for you. The SSMS screen shots you show certainly mean that SSMS can't find the column with that name in the table.